# How To make 2D Quantum dots in VESTA

Tags: density-functional-theory, vesta

I want to know how to make 2D Quantum dots in Vesta?

Comment: You might have to be a lot more specific.

Comment: You may check this tutorial [VESTA Software - Build Quantum Dot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4T_38TXvlsk),

Comment: Were you able to build 2D quantum dots in VESTA based on the tutorial provided in the answer (which was now turned into a comment) by JaafarMehrez?